# Disabling a button in a panel triggers CheckedChanged event on radio buttons in panel

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have encountered a very odd issue with the code I am working on. I have a Table Layout Panel that contains two smaller table layout panels. One contains 6 radio buttons to handle SMEMA modes while another contains buttons to handle conveyor actions (load, rewind).

Nested within the click event handler for the conveyor buttons, I have a function that disables the buttons while motion is active (segment below). I have found that when the line calls to disable the rewind button, the CheckedChanged event for the radio buttons suddenly fires. NOTE: This is only when one of the 6 buttons are selected.

```
bool isIdle = state.IsIdle;

//process tab
_buttonStartupRoutine.Enabled = isIdle;
_ckbuttonPLCRun.Enabled = true;
_buttonCameraMode.Enabled = isIdle;
_checkBoxDryRun.Enabled = isIdle;
_updownJogScale.Enabled = isIdle;
_buttonConveyorLoad.Enabled = isIdle;
_buttonConveyorUnload.Enabled = isIdle;
_buttonConveyorRewind.Enabled = isIdle;
_updownConveyorWidth.Enabled = isIdle;
```

I have confirmed that this line is causing the CheckedChanged event to fire by moving it higher in the call stack so it is called immediately when the Rewind button is clicked. However, I can't find any link between the two besides sharing the same general table layout panel, despite being in two separate nested panels.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this?

EDIT: With more troubleshooting I have confirmed that something is trickling down into the radio buttons. I added a foreach statement above the line that says *_buttonConveyorRewind.Enabled = isIdle;* that disables each radio button in the table layout panel. This also re-enabled them because it comes back through the attached code once the movement of the conveyor is complete.

```
foreach (RadioButton button in tableLayoutPanel22.Controls)
{
     button.Enabled = isIdle;
}
```

I also had to call the Focus event on the main panel to prevent the panel from jumping down below the panel of radio buttons. This seemed to prevent the radio buttons from changing and the SMEMA mode of the machine itself was remaining consistent as well. It would seem that a Focus event somewhere was trickling down and causing the radio buttons to change.

Comment: Is the `Enter` event of the RadioButtons subscribed to and performs some action? Or any other event related to focus change? Maybe something that changes the Checked status the RadioButtons when one is entered (or something similar)? Or any other Control that, when it receives the focus, activates the RadioButtons in some way?

Comment: The only event on all of the radio buttons is the CheckedChanged event. I've also placed a break on every single reference to the panel or radio buttons and I am still finding the same behavior. When I click the button, it starts the movement process in the machine which trickles down to a function that enables/disables the buttons. Once it hits the disabling of the rewind button, it instantly jumps into the CheckedChanged event. I have even commented it out and moved it higher in the call stack and the same behavior still shows.Not sure where to go besides just create a work around.

Comment: I'm sure you know what you're referring to when you mention *movement process*, *rewind button*, *moved it higher in the call stack*, but, most probably, nobody else does. You should post code that can reproduce this behavior. The Framework and System versions where this code is being tested is also important. --- You understand that RadioButtons don't raise the event by themselves. Something must set the Checked/CheckedState or trigger it because of cascading focus change events.

Comment: Jimi, thank you for helping here. I know the post wasn't very clear but I'm not certain what I can share. It would've also required adding a ton of code and explanation. In the end, it would seem that you are correct that there is some event occurring that is trickling into the radio buttons and causing the change. I was able to side-step this by adding a foreach loop that disables each radio button because they shouldn't be able to change while a process is active anyways. Once I did this, the issue went away and the focus after a click did change as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that an event was trickling down into either the panel or radio buttons. My solution was to disable each radio button using a foreach statement before disabling the conveyor buttons. This seemed to prevent the event from changing the buttons since they were disabled when it hit. I also had to manually call Focus() on the main panel to get the focus back up to the top of the scroll area. This would confirm that a focus event of some sort was causing the radio buttons to think they were changing. I have included the code change below.

```
foreach (RadioButton button in tableLayoutPanel22.Controls)
{
    button.Enabled = isIdle;
}
_Panel_Main.Focus();
```